# C++/CLI error C1189 when I Include marshal library

Tags: c++-cli, marshalling

I've got a application that is communicating with a [PLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller).

I have some libraries included for the communication but when I add marshal:

`#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>`

it gives me the following error:

C1189: #error: The C++ Standard Library forbids macroizing keywords. Enable warning C4005 to find the forbidden macros.

C4005: 'inline': macro redefinition

this C4005 warning shows in
xkeycheck.h line 203 which contains:

`#define inline EMIT WARNING C4005`

and I get a ton more of errors(1800+).

So what does this error mean?

Comment: Might help: [xkeycheck.h and macro defined keywords](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6cb13b36-1da5-49ec-895c-e002dfb7546a/xkeycheckh-and-macro-defined-keywords?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: @crashmstr and how do I define `_ALLOW_KEYWORD_MACROS` in my project settings?

Comment: C++ preprocessor settings to use for all files or add `#define ...` in the problem file above there the include that is causing the error.

Comment: xkeycheck.h already contains `_ALLOW_KEYWORD_MACROS`

Comment: Not in my copies (Visual Studio 2015 or 2010), but you would need to set it in the project settings or `#define` it before the first time that file is included.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, when I at the `_ALLOW_KEYWORD_MACROS ` it gives errors about my library. Kinda frustrating this isn't working. Just simply adding a .h file and it won't run anymore. And I know this is about defining or including stuff twice...

Comment: I'm guessing the libraries you are using have some things in the header that won't play well. If you can build a native C++ DLL or library first (to isolate the usage of the header into non-CLR code), then build a C++/CLI wrapper, that might work.

Comment: I'm new to C++/CLI, this is my first project working with some libraries and including them. Building a DLL or library isn't an option for me.

Comment: Then you might need to put the inclusion of the header files in a seperate file that does not use the C++/CLI functionality and then have C or C++ functions that use the library but don't require the usage of the header file elsewhere.

Comment: Yea, never mind I should find something else to convert my `unsigned char to System::String`.

Comment: `marshal_cppstd.h` is for converting to/from standard C++ strings (`std::string` and `std::wstring`). You can use `marshal.h` for C strings (you can search this site for examples).

Comment: I've read something also about converting `unsigned char` to `System::String^`. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19579/Using-and-extending-the-Orcas-marshal-as-library#_comments)

Answer (score 0):

`inline` is a C++ keyword which this `#define` is re-defining. It's warning you that it's pretty risky to change the meaning of `inline`.

`msclr\marshal_cppstd.h` has functions marked with `inline` so this is probably the first occurrence of code using the re-defined inline definition and it's realizing that it is probably not what you're expecting.

I would question why `xkeycheck.h` is redefining `inline` -- perhaps inlining is not allowed with their library?  Perhaps you need to push/pop the definition of `inline` around your include or `#undef inline` before your include?

**Update:** Did more research, I was assuming xkeycheck was from the PLC code. It's not.  So, xkeycheck is set up to report this error if it sees that you've redefine any of the C++ keywords. `inline` in this case.    As I said above, `marshal_cppstd.h` actually uses `inline` so that's the first sign of trouble and it's emitting the warning.   So.... my advice is to search all your code and find out where you or a header you include has #define'd `inline` to something else.

I would put the cursor on inline and press F12 to go to the definition.